# using jquery to show successfull form submission

Tags: php, jquery

i have the following javascript file named coupon.js -

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('.appnitro').submit( function() {
$.ajax({
            url     : $(this).attr('action'),
            type    : $(this).attr('method'),
            dataType: 'json',
            data    : $(this).serialize(),
            success : function( data ) {
                        for(var id in data) {
                            jQuery('#' + id).html( data[id] );
                        }
                      }

        });

        return true;
    });

});
```

sms.php -

```
<?php
//process form
$res = "message deliverd";
$arr = array( 'content' => $res );
echo json_encode( $arr );//end sms processing
unset ($_POST);
?>
```

i am calling like this -

```
    <form id="smsform" class="appnitro"  method="post" action="sms.php"> 
... 
<input id="saveForm" class="button_text" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
<div id="content"></div>
```

**Now i expected that after a successful form submission the div "content" would show the message without any page refresh.
But instead the page redirects to /sms.php and then outputs -**

```
{"content":"message deliverd"}
```

Please tell where i am going wrong. My javascript is correct . No error shown by firebug. **Or please tell some other method to acheive the reqd. functionality.**

Even this coupon.js is not working-

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(e){
        jQuery('.appnitro').submit( function() {
$.ajax({
            url     : $(this).attr('action'),
            type    : $(this).attr('method'),
            dataType: 'json',
            data    : $(this).serialize(),
            success : function( data ) {
                        for(var id in data) {
                            jQuery('#' + id).html( data[id] );
                        }
                      }

        });

e.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

Not working even if i add return fasle at end. **Please suggest some other method to acheive this functionality**

Comment: is your **coupons.js** file and jQuery api file is included in your html form file properly?

Comment: ya it is...click on grab button link here - http://174.132.194.155/~kunal17/devbuzzr/deals/5-discount-on-all-guitars

Comment: Your above code is working perfectly on my side without any change. But I included **coupon.js** file and **jquery-1.4.2.js** in html form file like this:`<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.js">``</script> <script type="text/javascript" src="coupon.js"></script>`

Comment: @NAVEED - i also did the same but still no success. Check now - http://174.132.194.155/~kunal17/devbuzzr/deals/5-discount-on-all-guitars

Comment: try doing alert json response in success funtion and see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why the page is refreshing is because the `submit` event wasn't suppressed.

There are two ways to do this:

- Accept an event object as a parameter to the event handler, then call `preventDefault()` on it.
- `return false` from the event handler.

Answer to your revised question: You are accepting the `e` parameter in the wrong function, you should accept it in the `submit` handler, not the `ready` handler.

Comment: +1, or `preventDefault()`, but either way, you need to prevent the default form submission.

Comment: check out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776004/jquery-ajax-request-firebug-error.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to cancel the form submission in your jquery.  From the jQuery documentation:

> Now when the form is submitted, the
>   message is alerted. This happens prior
>   to the actual submission, so we can
>   cancel the submit action by calling
>   .preventDefault() on the event object
>   or by returning false from our
>   handler. We can trigger the event
>   manually when another element is
>   clicked:

So in your code:

```
//add 'e' or some other handler to the function call   
 jQuery(document).ready(function(e){
            jQuery('.appnitro').submit( function() { $.ajax({
                url     : $(this).attr('action'),
                type    : $(this).attr('method'),
                dataType: 'json',
                data    : $(this).serialize(),
                success : function( data ) {
                            for(var id in data) {
                                jQuery('#' + id).html( data[id] );
                            }
                          }

            });
            //return false
            return false;

           //or
           e.preventDefault();
        });

    });
```